# Tomcat7 Restricting IP Address for manager

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat-manager

I'm trying to restrict access to the manager app but this doesnt work.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->
<Context path="/manager" privileged="true" docBase="/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/manager">
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="123\.123\.123\.123"/>
</Context>




</Context>
```

Comment: What file did you edit? You would normally edit `${tomcat_home}/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml`.

Comment: I edited /conf/context.xml

Comment: try this, add path="/manager" attribute to the context tag